# Is it possible to force eclipse (or java initiated via eclipse) to run in swap space rather than RAM on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ram

So I'm working on a netbook with 2 GB RAM available but I have 6 GB of swap space total - is it possible to force Java/eclipse to run in the swap space rather than in regular memory?

Using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: That's not how memory works.  The point of a swap file is to hold things that _aren't_ being used so that the RAM can be used for other things.

Comment: Note that even if you could, you wouldn't want to. It'd make Eclipse run more than 10x slower, and that's assuming a high-speed SSD.

Answer (score 3):

No program can run in swap space. Parts of the program get moved to swap space if ram is low, but they have to moved back to ram to execute them. Your OS will handle that without you noticing.